# Are Vishnu, Shiva and Brahma the same?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vedas, brahma

According to Vedas the God is One. Can I know who is the "real" God ?.Are Vishnu , Shiva and Brahma all the manifestation of the supreme Paramatman ?? If Vishnu, Shiva and Brahma are the manifestation of Paramatman, what about Ganesha, Hanuman and Durga ?? Are they paramatman too ??

Comment: As per Advaita Perspective There is nothing second than Brahman/God. Hence everything is Supreme God... For Vaishnavs Vishnu is their supreme... For Gaudiyas Krishna is their supreme... For Shaivites Shiva is their supreme... For Shaktas and Ganapatys Durga and Ganesh are supreme... For Ramanandis Lord Rama is supreme... Similarly there can be devotees for Brahma and Hanuman etc. etc. **Tulsidas says "Jaa ki Rahi Bhawana Jaisi Prabhu Murat Dekhi Tinn Taisi"  or people see face of God as per their emotions and feelings..** Each also validate their way by quoting their own scriptures...

Comment: The three referred to are known as the Trimurti. In some parts of the Vedas these are the three aspects of Saguna Brahman when seen in its aspects of creator, preserver, and destroyer of the universe. But there are also some who worship and see the Supreme Godhead (Saguna Brahman) through Vishnu and Shiva. Ganesha and Hanuman are not worshiped as the Supreme Godhead. Durga is worshiped by some as the embodiment of Saguna Brahman.

Comment: I say specifically Saguna Brahman as the Unmanifested Nirguna Brahman cannot be worshiped; the Saguna Brahman is the Nirguna Brahman when seen from 'inside' this universe, from within maya.

Answer (score 2):

All of them can be seen as different aspects of the Paramatman serving different purposes:

> There are three forces: Brahma shakti, Vishnu shakti, and Shiva
>   shakti. You may have one of these predominant. Brahma shakti is the
>   force to create something new. Vishnu shakti is maintenance and Shiva
>   shakti is bringing in transformation, filling in life, or destroying.
>
> Some of you have Brahma shakti. You may create well, but you may not
>   be able to maintain. For example, you may make friends very fast, but
>   it does not last long.
>
> There are others who cannot create but are good at maintaining. For
>   example, people have long lasting friendships but cannot make any new
>   friends. In such cases, Vishnu shakti is dominant.
>
> And then there are others who have more of Shiva shakti. They bring in
>   new life or transformation or they can destroy the whole set up.
>
> In Guru shakti, all three shaktis have blossomed fully.
>
> So each of you first identify which shakti you have more of and aspire
>   for Guru shakti. Guru makes a group but a group cannot make a Guru.

From an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom/knowledge-sheets/who-are-you-brahma-vishnu-mahesh-or-guru

Hope this helps! :)